# Reads a number and should be counted as a symbol

Tags: c, scanf, symbols

I want to make a program that reads a list of numbers (one per line) in from the standard input using `scanf()` and prints a sideways graph.

For example, I used with my data file I created:

> ./p6 < test/p6-testdata
>
> 5: #####
>   40:########################################
>   51:###################################################
>   ...
>   26:##########################
>   46:##############################################
>   14:##############

Here is my code I have tried for the first time:

```
int main ()
{

  int i;      //i is integer and s is symbol
  char s = '#'; //s is a character with symbol should be converted

  printf ("Enter an integer\n");
  scanf ("%d", &i);
  i = s; // i is an interger from input should be converted to s

  printf ("%d: %d\n", i, s); 

  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Enter an integer
35: 35
```

I don't understand why or how?

Please help me.

Comment: What is it that you don't understand?

Comment: You need a loop to repeat the letter across your graph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple approach is to read the numbers from your file (example below reads `stdin`) and then loop the number of times outputting the fill character `'#'` followed by a newline. Repeat as long as you read valid integer input from your file.

A short example would be:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define FILL '#'

int main (void) {

    int n;

    while (scanf ("%d", &n) == 1) {     /* for each valid input */
        printf ("%2d: ", n);            /* output the number n */
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)     /* loop n times */
            putchar (FILL);             /* outputting FILL char */
        putchar ('\n');                 /* tidy up with newline */
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ echo "1 3 5 10 12 18 14 11 9 4 2" | ./bin/graphsideways
 1: #
 3: ###
 5: #####
10: ##########
12: ############
18: ##################
14: ##############
11: ###########
 9: #########
 4: ####
 2: ##
```

or for your numbers:

```
$ echo "5 40 51 26 46 14" | ./bin/graphsideways
 5: #####
40: ########################################
51: ###################################################
26: ##########################
46: ##############################################
14: ##############
```

You can simply add the `FILE*` pointer and open (and validate the file is open) before reading your file with `fscanf` instead of `scanf`.

Let me know if you have further questions.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you're getting 35:35 printed is because you first copy # into i and then print both s and i as integers (%d).  # in ascii is 35.

The specifier to print a character is %c.

Answer (score -1):

You need some kind of loop to print out the '#'

Also, you should use %c for printing the char

```
int main ()
{

int i;      //i is integer and s is symbol
int x;
char s = '#'; //s is a character with symbol should be converted

printf ("Enter an integer\n");
scanf ("%d", &i);

printf ("%d: ", i); 

for( x = 0; x < i; x = x + 1 ){
    printf ("%c", s);  
}

printf ("\n"); 


return 0;
}
```

[edit to replace %s with %c]

Comment: You can't use %s with a character.  _s_ is not a string so doing %s is incorrect.

Comment: You can call `putchar('#')` instead of `char s = '#'; ...; printf ("%c", s);`.